# What is the physical reason of having $-fx^4$ term in explaining thermal expansion?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

In Kittel's Introduction to Solid State Physics, Seventh edition- Page 130, he accounted for the thermal expansion of solids by considering the potential energy of the atoms to be $$U(x)=cx^2-gx^3-fx^4$$ where $x$ is the departure from the equilibrium separation of atoms i.e. the lattice constant $a$. If $x<0$, it implies that the atoms are trying to come closer than their equilibrium separation $a$. This would cost energy due to Lennard-Jones type of atom-atom repulsion. This is taken into account by the term $-gx^3$.

However, Kittel also says that the term $-fx^4$ represents the "softening of vibration at large amplitudes". What I can see is that when $x>0$ and is large, that decreases the potential energy. But this is counterintuitive because for $x>0$ and as it increases, the potential energy must increase by the simple Lennard-Jones form.

Comment: For me, it is unclear why you speak that cubic term is related to Lennard-Jones potential

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov      Lennard-Jones potential is a model for the atom-atom interaction potential. For small excursions around the minimum of this potential (which is at equilibrium lattice separation of the atoms), Taylor expansion will give rise to a quadratic (harmonic) term at the leading order and anharmonic terms at the subleading order.

Comment: *when $x>0$ and is large* This is an approximation for small $x$ so you are thinking about the expression outside it's intended use.

Comment: @Soumita 1) anharmonic terms occurs due to phonon-phonon interaction, 2) L-J terms goes from electromagnetic interaction via zero modes of electromagnetic field.

Comment: @StephenG I am not sure. When you explicitly write non-quadratic terms, it seems that you can consider large enough displacements from equilibrium.

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov      1) When the Hamiltonian cut off at the quadratic order, its quantization to give (noninteracting) phonons. The phonon-phonon interaction, on the other hand, pops up only when the potential is not cut off at the quadratic order but the anharmonic terms are also retained. It's not the other way around as you say i.e., $x^3$ or $x^4$ terms don't come from phonon-phonon interactions. They lead to phonon-phonon interactions.

Comment: 2) The attractive part of the LJ potential is the attraction between two fluctuating dipoles and the repulsive part comes from Pauli's exclusion principle. It's a generic potential form used to describe atom-atom interaction potential.

Comment: @Soumita okey :)

Comment: @StephenG "large amplitudes" is not a phrase that I used. It is used by Kittel himself. The point is (as far as I get) $x$ is small compared to $a$. With this, a whole continuum of values are possible of $x$ including values such as $x<<<a$ or values such as $x<<a$ etc. To give an example, if the lattice constant is $\sim 1$ Angstrom, then $x\sim 10^{-1}$ Angstroom is larger than $x\sim 10^{-2}$ or $10^{-3}$ Angstrom.

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov  Is that supposed to be an agreement or a disagreement? Just to be clear, by LJ potential I meant any potential of the form $U(r)\sim \frac{a}{r^m}-\frac{b}{r^n}$ where $a,b$ are positive constants and $m,n$ are two integers which usually have the value 12 and 6. And I also agree that part of the LJ potential can be understood as coming from zero-point energy.